# How to customize the Junit's testcase calling functionality

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I don't want the Junit to call my test methods/selenium testcases sequentially. But i want the particular testcase to execute or it should get called as per my need.

Example code:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;


public class demo2 {
    Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.co.in/");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.setTimeout("6000");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_3() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("q", "3");
    }
    @Test
    public void test_4() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("q", "4");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

**Note**

I want the the methods test_3,test_4.... should be called depending on the condition.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Assume` class from JUnit. You can read more in http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assume.html for usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html)

```
assumeTrue(conditionIsFulfilled)
```

From the doc:

> A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken, but that the
>   test provides no useful information. The default JUnit runner treats
>   tests with failing assumptions as ignored. Custom runners may behave
>   differently.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG allows this via the @dependsOnMethods annotation.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

If you are stuck with JUnit, then write your own RunsWith, that you could use to add the same or similar functionality based on your needs.

A great example is seen here: [Specifying an order to junit 4 tests at the Method level (not class level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089151/specifying-an-order-to-junit-4-tests-at-the-method-level-not-class-level)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing different @test, you can write those test as normal java methods and write only one test.

in that test you can call any method based on some condition.

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;


public class demo2 {
    Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.google.co.in/");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.setTimeout("6000");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        if(<condition1>){
          method1(selenium);
        }  
        if(<condition2>){
          method2(selenium);
        }  
        if(<condition3>){
          method3(selenium);
        }  
        if(<condition4>){
          method4(selenium);
        }  

    }

    public static void method1(Selenium selenium) 
    throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("q", "1");
    }

    public static void method2(Selenium selenium) 
    throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("q", "2");
    }

    public static void method3(Selenium selenium) 
    throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("q", "3");
    }

    public static void method4(Selenium selenium) 
    throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("q", "4");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            selenium.stop();
    }
}
```