# JUnit4 - different timeout for 'same' test cases

Tags: java, junit, timeout

I have a problem with JUnit4 and it's `@Test(timeout=xxx)` annotation. For example, two tests with same body, different name. None of them uses any global variables which can be initialized.
When I run tests it has totally different execution time (First test 0,811s, second 0,143).

It's very important for me to get similar results. Is there any way to resolve/workaround this problem ?

Comment: It would be easier to help if we could see the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probable that the first test is reported as having taken longer because this includes the setup time JUnit takes to initialize the class. If you have 2 tests that need to run in approximitely the same amount of time, consider adding a third test before the other two just to get the init stuff out of the way.

Let me know if this works, am curious.

Comment: Yes, you're right :) thanks. It's stragne behavior of JUnit library, class initialization time should not affect for method execution time.

Comment: The ordering of test-method invocations is not guaranteed in JUnit. If you really want to specify the order, read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089151/specifying-an-order-to-junit-4-tests-at-the-method-level-not-class-level

Answer (score 0):

Try using a timeout rule instead. The class will have been initialized before the timeout rule is applied, so class initialization time *should* be excluded.